# Excel Graph with dynamic x-axis properties

Tags: excel, vba, dynamic-programming

In Excel, I have a table of contents and a graph of this table  where the X-axis can vary with regards to beginning and end. How can I set the X-axis range dynamically, so that it is not always using the whole table like below? I'm currently having to go into the graph settings and change it manually..
[image]

Here is my data table:
[image]

The min_max column I just added becaue I thought it might be useful.

Depending on a combo-box selection the "Calenderweek" selection varies. so I would like the graph to adapt to the calenderweek range, instead of having the huge gap on the right.
How would the offset formula look like? I tried it, but not succesfully.

Thanks.

Comment: Try named range with offset function to select dynamic range based on criteria. In in selection of data for the chart you can use the named range instead of manually changing it. Also, it would be better to present a sample data you are creating chart with.

Comment: In the developer tab record a macro where you create and individualize your diagram as you want it to look like. Afterstopping the record, in the module you can see the steps you did and can try to reproduce them and where you hae to change individual values. If you already have some code, you may show us what you already did and we can help you out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Named ranges will help as below

```
first create named ranges as below                              
Name                Result      Name Range Formula                      
FirstNonBlankRow_ColB       4       =INDEX(ROW(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$13),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX((Sheet1!$B$2:$B$13<>0),0),0))                        
FirstNonBlankCellRef_ColA   Range A4    =OFFSET(Sheet1!$A$1,INDEX(ROW(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$13),MATCH(TRUE,INDEX((Sheet1!$B$2:$B$13<>0),0),0))-1,,1,1)                     
ChartData_ColA          Range A4 to A8  =OFFSET(FirstNonBlankCellRef_ColA,,,COUNTA(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$13),1)                        
ChartData_ColB          Range B4 to B8  =OFFSET((FirstNonBlankCellRef_ColA),,1,COUNTA(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$13),1)                     
ChartData_ColC          Range C4 to C8  =OFFSET((FirstNonBlankCellRef_ColA),,2,COUNTA(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$13),1)                     
ChartData_ColD          Range D4 to D8  =OFFSET((FirstNonBlankCellRef_ColA),,3,COUNTA(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$13),1)                     
ChartData_ColE          Range E4 to E8  =OFFSET((FirstNonBlankCellRef_ColA),,4,COUNTA(Sheet1!$B$2:$B$13),1)                     

Then add these names rangs in chart "Select Data" box like                              
Series Name =Sheet1!$B$1            Horizontal (Category) Axis Labels               =Book1!ChartData_ColA
Series Values   =Book1!ChartData_ColB
```

[image]

Comment: This will automatically update with chart data ignoring blank rows in col B to E .. Make sure in named ranges referring to cell ranges absolutely and not relatively .. like $A$! and not just A1 .. [please accept/ upvote if this answers your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers#:~:text=%20To%20accept%20an%20answer%3A%20%201%20Choose,un-accept%20the%20answer%2C%20at%20any%20time.%20More%20)

Comment: ..just that I have to use <>"" instead of <>0 in the two formulas, and I guess that affects my range on the tail side.

Comment: Caqn you explain the -1,1,1 part of FirstNonBLockCellRef_ColA please?

Comment: @KingsleyObeng ... If you see offset function .. It starts from a range ..and then it offsets from there.. In this case it starts from A1 and then it offsets 4 rows with index function.. then it will go to A5.. But we need to deduct 1 to make it go to A4 where the chart data should start.. And ending 1,1 represent width and height of offset.. In this case we want only one cell A4 therefore both of them are 1,1

Comment: thanks for that..Is it possible the COUNTA(XX,1) doesn't work if there are formulas where there are blanks? With COUNTIF(XX,>0) I have solved that little problem;)

Comment: Can you please update the image of your data so that I can understand it better?  ....Or ... are the blank cells result of a formula? Say .. Iferror(_,"")? .. If so you can change it to iferror(_na()) and make conditional formatting for error as white font :) ... Index formula here finds the row number of the first nonblank cell in B2:B13

Comment: When replace errors or blank cells ("") with NA() function, chart ignores those data points and other points are plotted.