# Easiest way to automate the creation of charts given an input Excel file

Tags: excel, powerquery

I'd like to automate the creation of monthly reports. I have a database through which I can export an Excel file (or csv, for the record). The table format is such that the number of columns (~500) will always be the exact same, but the number of rows (25-100) is variable.

The end goal is an excel tab with a few graphs/charts based on said data. For the charts, I'll only need to use maybe 10 columns of data out of the 500, but all of the rows.

I would like to automate the creation of this report as much as possible. Ideally, it will be able to be used by people with limited Excel knowledge. I would think I could set it up such that they can export the file out of the database, input it into my created sheet, and receive an output of charts.

This seems simple but I can't find much info on something like this. I just want to tell Excel "for every inputted file, make a pie chart out of these columns, a line graph out of these columns, a bar graph out of these...etc etc"

Power Query is where I started, and it helped to clean up the large number of unneeded columns, but I don't see where the functionality to automatically create charts comes into play. Macros/VBA seemed like an obvious next step, but I'm worried about how to set it up such that other users won't have to mess with the macros to get a desired end result. Again, ideally it would be as simple as inputted a file path, clicking a button, and getting graphs outputted.

Any tips or advice on how to approach this or what Excel tools that would be easiest to use would be great. Thank you in advance!

Comment: Can you copy the already completed file for previous month and overwrite the data for new month? Then you don't have to create new graphs. Old graphs can be populated with truly dynamic (both ends dynamic, first and last cell referenced) named ranges for the varying number of rows. As you have mentioned using power query to import and clean the data, you may not need VBA at all.

Comment: @Naresh thanks so much. Yeah, I was considering some way of copying it but was worried with the variable number of rows. Do you mind explaining how I can make it "truly dynamic"? Thank you again.

Comment: Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68228804/9808063) for truly dynamic named ranges with first and last cell matched with a given criteria. Also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68512455/excel-how-to-achieve-the-equivalent-result-of-using-ctrlend-by-using-functi/68515893#68515893)